# How to find bat file name in function

Tags: batch-file

The name of the bat file is the 0th parameter, `%0%`. But inside a label, when the label is invoked as a function, using the `call:` syntax, it is the label itself:

```
@echo off
echo in bat file:%0%
echo calling..
call :USAGE
echo goto..
goto :USAGE
goto :EOF

:USAGE
echo in label:%0%
goto :EOF
```

In a file named t.bat, this produces the following: output

```
C:\builds>c:\tmp\t.bat
in bat file:c:\tmp\t.bat
calling..
in label::USAGE
goto..
in label:c:\tmp\t.bat
```

Is there a way to get the bat file name inside the `:call`?

Comment: @Stephan do you have any reason to believe that will change anything?

Comment: `%0%` is acceptable syntax in bat file, apparently. Your comment suggests using `%0` fixes the problem, which it doesn't.

Comment: This may be a language issue, but your sentence construction certainly suggests (to me) that you were proposing a solution -- it is not unusual on SO to give terse solution as comments. Not sure what you are pointing out with `%0%%username%`; `echo %0%username` does not give sensible output either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any variable reference modifier on `%0` inside the label to obtain a reference to the current batch file

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    call :label

    endlocal
    exit /b

:label

    echo label : %0 
    echo file  : %~f0
    echo file  : %~nx0
    goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but you can specify the batch file name as an argument when calling the label, thus making it available as the first parameter inside the label execution:

```
@echo off

echo My batch file is %0
call :USAGE %0
goto :EOF

:USAGE
echo USAGE my batch file is %1
```

Output:

> D:\Temp>test.bat
>   My batch file is test.bat
>   USAGE my batch file is test.bat

Comment: My current solution is to initialize a variable such as BAT_FILE_NAME at the top, which is similar